# Transparent menu in revolution slider wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, menubar, revolution-slider

I'm using the X theme by themeco and Revolution slider I want to make the menu bar transparent with the slider behind it, so that the top of the slider is the background of the menu bar. If I make the menu bar transparent, it just shows up as white above the slider, no overlap.

Here is the link to the site: http://845.b40.myftpupload.com/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the code but you could absolutely position the header to the top of the page, using something like:

```
header{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background:transparent;
 }
```

Comment: So I added that to the global css and it worked pretty well as you can see if you go back to the site. However, now the menu seems to be a sidebar or compressed on the right side.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the correct link as there's no menu in the webpage I see at all.  But from the sounds of what you are describing, adding the properties - width: 100%, left: 0 and right: 0 to the header CSS could solve this

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to add a second menu (also transparent if possible) to the bottom of the revolution slider, but I'm not sure how.
Thank you!

Comment: Again, without seeing the correct link it's hard to say.  But if you can place the bottom menu inside the slider you could give the slider a property of - position:relative.  Then absolutely position the menu to the bottom of it using - position: absolute and bottom:0